# Tag warning only shown for a second when I post directly after adding tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, warning, tag-warnings

When I do the following:

1. write the title and body of a question;
2. go to the tag field;
3. add a tag that triggers a [tag warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/2127008);
4. do not defocus the tag window;
5. hit *Post your question;*

then I only see the tag warning for roughly a second before the freshly posted question loads.

But see for yourself:

[image: Animation showing bug]

(Note: The way tag warnings are displayed has completely changed recently as of September 2018. This issue was unaffected by this.)

This renders tag warnings pretty pointless in this case, as new users will not know what they just saw and how to reproduce it, let alone heed the warning. Moreover, as adding a tag is the last thing most new users will do with their questions before posting, this is a highly relevant case.

The same applies if I add a tag triggering a tag warning during an edit.

This problem might extend to all other “yellow” warnings as well.

Comment: Before anybody asks: Yes, *F* and *Q* are next to each other on my keyboard.

Comment: This is now fixed in [the new ask interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/255554).