# Can we change when tag warnings display?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-warnings

Tag warnings are meant to [warn users of known, frequent pitfalls](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/7317818) when posting certain content. They are [crafted on a per-site basis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298887/311001) with guidance specific to each situation.

Tag warnings pop up (best I can tell) the first time focus *leaves* the "tags" field. I suspect many users post following the natural top-bottom order suggested by the ask page: title, text, tags, click "Post Your Question." (Perhaps a UX expert on SE staff can tell us how common that is?) Which gives us the following experience: [Tag warning only shown for a second when I post directly after adding tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278399/311001).

Is it possible to change when the tag-warning *displays* to improve the chances that people who need to see them actually do while there's time to re-think whatever the warning's pointing at?

Comment: I've been complaining about this (and the positioning) since 2015 (on a [child meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/feature-guidelines-for-identify-this-questions-reposition)). It's a known problem but I don't know if there's a fix.

Comment: This is sort of fixed with the new ask page, is it not? The tag warning is now shown on the right side of the review page when asking a question. (This is true whether you include the tag that has a tag warning initially and then click "review", or if you add the tag after clicking "review" but before clicking "post".) ...Though I'm not sure if issues still occur based on where cursor focus is if editing after the question's posted.